# ParcelJs: bundle an html file that contains an anchor tag and that is not an entry point

Tags: javascript, html, parceljs

I have a simple web application (no frameworks) that I am bundling with **Parcel**. It has a `pages` folder and a `components` folder. Components are just bits of html that I want to reuse throughout the application. Pages are the entry-points of the bundle (`parcel build pages/index.html pages/*/*.html`).
Components are made of an **html** file and a **javascript** file. I import the **html** into the **javascript** with `bundle-text:`, create a DOM element with the string result and then append it to the document. The javascript file is then imported in files in the `pages` directory.
The problem is that if I use an anchor tag inside a component where the `href` points to a file in `/pages` the bundle is broken. It cannot resolve the paths correctly. If I use a path relative to where the component is imported eg. `<a href="/someFolderInPages/index.html>` Parcel cannot find the correct file: `@parcel/core: Failed to resolve '/someFolderInPages/index.html' from './components/comp-1/index.html'`.
If I use a path that goes from `/components` to `/pages` eg. `<a href="../pages/someFolderInPages/index.html>` it says: `Error: Bundles must have unique names`.
Is there a way to fix this or should I drop the html file in the components completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference pages from components with the style `/someFolderInPages/index.html`, the error you get is probably expected - the `/` at the beginning is an "absolute specifier" and tells parcel [to start at the project root](https://parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#absolute-specifiers). So you'd probably need to write `/pages/someFolderInPages/index.html` or `/src/pages/someFolderInPages/index.html` (depending on how your project is structured) for parcel to be able to find the source file you want correctly.

However, that won't really solve your problem, because the second error you get (when you use the style `"../pages/someFolderInPages/index.html"`) is what will happen when you parcel *does* resolve the dependency. This appears to me to be a possible bug in parcel - feel free to file a github issue if you'd like.

However, there might be a better way to accomplish what you want that has the side-effect of avoiding this bug. You said "Components are just bits of html that I want to reuse throughout the application" - if that's all they are, it would be more performant for the users of your application if they were inserted into pages at build-time instead of run-time.

Parcel can do exactly this with `.pug` templates (see [parcel docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/pug/) and [pug docs](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html)).

For example, a "component" might have some re-usable snippet of html (expressed in pug syntax):

**/src/components/someComponent.pug**

```
a(href="../pages/someFolderInPages/index.pug") Link from a component to a page
```

Then, you could included in a "page" like this:

**/src/page/anotherFolderInPages/index.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  body
    h1 The link from the component will show up below:
    include ../../components/someComponent.pug
```

Parcel will take care of building the page at compile-time (turning it into an `.html` file), so there's no need for a separate javascript bundle to download and execute at runtime just to insert some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use a path that goes from /components to /pages eg. <a
> href="../pages/someFolderInPages/index.html> it says: Error: Bundles
> must have unique names.

Yes, any links in your index.html mentioning another "index.html" will yield this *"unique names"* error message from parcel. And moreover, suppose you'd use different .html files to avoid this error message, all of your url arguments (?parameter=abc) will be removed by Parcel.. A link like

```
   <a href="src/car.html?koenigsegg&radius0=30&hx=0.8&hy=0.8">Koenigsegg</a><br>
```

.. is changed by Parcel into

```
   <a href="src/car.html">Koenigsegg</a><br>
```

As the first answer already indicated, these are in fact bugs in Parcel, there exist several complaint threads on github about it, [version 1](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1186/) as well as [version 2](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6048).. and [this one..](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6433)

The acknowledged answer may work fine for most projects, but my current project is just a little test program. I'd like to circumvent the issue, without using pug files and change every link. I worked around these issues by injecting my <a href links using Javascript instead of putting them in the html directly,

change

```
  <div id="links">
   <a href="index.html?koenigsegg&radius0=30&hx=0.8&hy=0.8">Koenigseggie</a><br>
   <a href="index.html?rubik&radius0=15&hx=0.8&hy=0.8">Rubiks cubie</a><br>
   <a href="index.html?building&radius0=45&hx=-0.68&hy=0.47">Building</a><br>
   <a href="index.html?chair&radius0=15&hx=0.8&hy=0.8">Chair</a><br>
   <a href="index.html?cube&radius0=10&hx=1.9&hy=0.8">File texture</a><br>
  </div>
```

into

```
  <div id="links">
    <!-- do not expose a href links to Parcel -->
  </div>          

  <!-- Parcel won't touch links in Javascript string.. -->
  <script language="Javascript">
  var linksdiv = document.getElementById("links");
  linksdiv.innerHTML = `
  Stills<br>
  <p>
   <a href="index.html?koenigsegg&radius0=30&hx=0.8&hy=0.8">Koenigseggie</a><br>
   <a href="index.html?rubik&radius0=15&hx=0.8&hy=0.8">Rubiks cubie</a><br>
   <a href="index.html?building&radius0=45&hx=-0.68&hy=0.47">Building</a><br>
   <a href="index.html?chair&radius0=15&hx=0.8&hy=0.8">Chair</a><br>
   <a href="index.html?cube&radius0=10&hx=1.9&hy=0.8">File texture</a><br>
  </p>
  Animations<br>
  <p>
   <a href="index.html?skeleton&radius0=80&hx=-0.68&hy=0.47">Swirling bone</a><br>
  </p>`;
 </script>
```